# Are there any builtin features of Go (the go compiler more likely) that address making your binary more tamper resistant?

Tags: security, go, cracking

I have a program that prompts for a PIN before performing particular actions. The PIN is stored, encrypted, in a local config file along side the executable binary. User enters PIN, program decrypts and compares to the stored value, if they are equal, ok, if not etc.

I'm aware this kind of security check could potentially be circumvented with forensic tools that alter the binary, in affect, changing the '==' to '!=' in the right place to make all the wrong PIN's pass the test in my example.

This may be a stupid question, as I know from the first 2 minutes of googling it's a big and challenging topic, but I still thought I should start with checking on features of the language/compiler I'm actually using first. So, are there any features natively available with Go to make this kind of attack harder to successfully perform?

Comment: First thing on my mind is obfuscation. Making reverse engineering harder. Looks like golang has stuff like this too: https://github.com/unixpickle/gobfuscate

Comment: If the user has this level of access then they can circumvent the pin, period. This is why access controls have to be applied to the user. It's impossible to give more detail without know what the "particular actions" your program performs are.

Comment: Note that it is impossible to solve this entirely unless you can run on a trusted platform that only accepts signed code. So in the end you must use obfuscation techniques or - if you're really prepared to dive deep - white box cryptography.

Answer (score 6):

No, there is nothing remotely like this in the official go compiler or standard library.